# Azure Bot Service registration is not creating the related Application

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I have developed a endpoint to be used for an skype bot but I have not hosted it in Azure so in order to be use skype channel I need registered it using Azure Bot Service (Bot Channels Registration). I did it but when I try create a App Password for that then Azure redirect me to Application Page and show me this message (In the image the message appears in Spanish but this is the translation):

> The application no longer exists or is not associated with your
>   account.

I have tried clear the cache of my browser and try using private tab too but nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Are you a member or a guest of the directory the bot was created in?  https://aad.portal.azure.com "Users can register applications" should be set to "Yes" and if you are a guest in the directory, then "Guest users permissions are limited" should be set to "No"

Answer (score 0):

> The application no longer exists, or is not associated with your account.

Based on my test, if I login to **Application Registration Portal** using the account that is not used to create **Bot Channels Registration** bot service, I get same message. Please check the account you are using to login to **Application Registration Portal** and make sure that account is same one you used to create your **Bot Channels Registration** bot service.

[image]

Besides, please check if others know your account and delete that app. You can also try to create another **Bot Channels Registration** bot service and check if same issue appears.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the account issue. But this does happen if you even create the new one. But what I do think is that there may be some sort of problem with the App Registration portal, or to be specific the link between the app registration portal API that generates auto id and password so if you are using the auto create Microsoft App ID and Password you would face this issue. But if you will do that manually from the App registration portal and use that in your bot channel or web app bot it should work fine. Hope that help.